# Can't execute pyinstaller application with implemented pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have a problem with executing application with pandastable implemented. It work properly in VSC, but ive got a fatal error as exe (compiled with pyinstaller). Any idea?

Im using Pandas, Tkinter, PandasTable and only attaching(just importing) pandastable cause an error. ("Failed to execute script MyScriptName")

> > > from pandastable import Table

TIA

Comment: You should include the error that you are getting.

Comment: @Shyrtle ... thx ... updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following parameters to the PyInstaller command.

```
pyinstaller --add-data="<FilePath to pandastable folder>\\pandastable\\";"pandastable" --hidden-import="pandastable" MyScriptName.py
```

Usually the pandastable folder is in Lib\site-packages\.